# Usefulness of bool* in C#

Tags: c#, byte, unsafe, boolean

Can I use `bool*` in any kind of meaningful way. How would I convert `bool*` to a `byte` for instance, or store `bool*` in a byte

My goal is to manage my own memory in a project of mine, the specifics aren't important, just something id like to do. Now I would like to be able to store my own variables, and i happen to need to store a boolean value. How can i, using `unsafe` and a `byte*`, store this boolean value, and utilize my space best? Ideally to store 4 bits in the byte.

Comment: Can you write with code, what do you want to do?

Comment: I would rather use `Nullable<bool>` or `bool?` in short form. Pointers are used like that in unsafe code. If you want to convert using general convention, use `byte b = (someBool ? (byte)1 : (byte)0);`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but why would you want to manage your own memory of the whole idea of C# is *not to manage your own memory*? Consider using C++ with .NET, easy enough to do, and you have all the freedom you want, including managing your memory.

Comment: Bear in mind that pointers differ on 32b and 64b machines (although you can use `ulong` on both to be safe). All the external variables should be inside the `fixed` statement so they do not get moved by GC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# you wouldn't normally use a `bool*`, which is something you can only use in unsafe code (which brings forth a whole lot of other stuff like pinning objects and so forth). A `bool*` would be a pointer to a boolean. A pointer is 4 bytes long and cannot be converted to a byte without loss.

Why would you want to do this and where do you encounter this? Normally, there's not easily a use case for using pointers in C# unless you have a very specific demand (i.e., an API call, but that you can solve using P/Invoke).

**EDIT:** (because you edited your q.)

The following code snippet shows you how to get the address of a boolean variable and how to convert that pointer to an `int` (converting to `byte` is not possible, we need four bytes).

```
unsafe
{
    // get pointer to boolean
    bool* boolptr = &mybool;                

    // get the int ptr (not necessary though, but makes following easier)
    int* intptr = (int*)boolptr;

    // get value the pointer is pointing at
    int myint = *intptr;

    // get the address as a normal integer
    int myptraddress = (int) intptr;
}
```

you say "ideally store 4 bits in a byte". Unless you have a 4-bits machine architecture, I'd strongly advice against it because it will make retrieving and storing the booleans very slow. But more importantly: you are talking C# here, not C++. C# is bound to the CLR which states that a boolean is stored as a byte and that each memory address is four bytes long in 32 bits architectures, which means pointers are four bytes long. Hence, your question, converting a bool* (pointer to a bool) to something else can only be converted into an integer or other datatype that is four bytes wide.

A tip: using flags you can utilize space best: this makes enum types take up a bit for each flag, which gives you eight booleans for each byte.

Comment: Watch out, `myptraddress` should be an `uint` for 32b system and `ulong` for 64b systems. Also `mybool` should be in a `fixed` statement outside of the `unsafe` block.

Comment: @Jaroslav: good points. There's a lot more to say about dealing with unsafe code. I wanted to give a little example, the `int` being a poor choice indeed (but not necessarily wrong). Note that `fixed` is not needed when the variables are value types and are initialized on the stack.