# C# - Convert from bool to bool*

Tags: c#, methods, casting, boolean

I need to do use a specific method to get a job done - it cannot be any other method or assembly. The method takes the following parameters:

```
void method(bool* isOn) {/* Some code... */}
```

I try to use false for the the parameter 'isOn', but Visual Studio tells "Argument 1: cannot convert from type 'bool' to 'bool*'".

How do I convert/use bool* so that it will act appropriately?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [Usefulness of bool* in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222676/usefulness-of-bool-in-c-sharp) because I am asking specifically about a conversion from a pointer to a type and a type itself. Also, the thread mentioned asks for the uses of bool*, but does not directly answer my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usefulness of bool\* in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222676/usefulness-of-bool-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Did you tag this with C# when you meant C++?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Some of it is, but this method is just marked with unsafe.

Comment: @Steve Wellens No, I meant C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass `false`, because constants do not have an address.

In order to pass a pointer to `false`, make a variable, set it to `false`, and use `&` operator to take variable's address:

```
unsafe class Program {

    static void foo(bool* b) {
        *b = true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        bool x = false;
        Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints false
        foo(&x);
        Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints true
    }

}
```

Note how the method is allowed to change the variable through a pointer.

Comment: Simple and to the point. Also taught me a little about the uses of the unsafe keyword. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

bool * is a pointer to a variable of type bool, not the bool value type.  Meaning what you need to pass is the memory reference to a Boolean variable, not the boolean value type itself:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z19tbbca.aspx

When you call the method, what you should be able to do is as follows:

```
bool isOn=false;

method(&isOn);
```

& address operator returns the memory address reference that the parameter appears to be  requiring.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx

Note, you may need to use unsafe context/compiler options for this to work, but assume you are already from what you've said.

Comment: I wish I could mark this one as a solution as well - good references and with a simple example. Thank you